# Counting consecutive rows - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to count consecutive rows based on value in other column.

I'm totally newbish when it comes to SQL - so ask on if something is unclear.

I have SQL Server 2008, so `LEAD()` and `LAG()` don't come into play, same with OVER() with window size base on partition.

Example data set:

```
SLOT                    Blocked 
-------------------------------
2015-02-09 07:00:00.000 0
2015-02-09 07:15:00.000 0
2015-02-09 07:30:00.000 0
2015-02-09 07:45:00.000 1
2015-02-09 08:00:00.000 1
2015-02-09 08:15:00.000 1
2015-02-09 08:30:00.000 0
2015-02-09 08:45:00.000 0
2015-02-09 09:00:00.000 0
2015-02-09 09:15:00.000 0
2015-02-09 09:30:00.000 1
2015-02-09 09:45:00.000 1
2015-02-09 10:00:00.000 1
2015-02-09 10:15:00.000 1
2015-02-09 10:30:00.000 0
2015-02-09 10:45:00.000 0
2015-02-09 11:00:00.000 0
2015-02-09 11:15:00.000 0
2015-02-09 11:30:00.000 0
2015-02-09 11:45:00.000 0
2015-02-09 12:00:00.000 0
```

The data is ordered by `SLOT`. I would like to count the rows over partitions `where Blocked = 0`.

The result set i would like to get:

```
SLOT                    Blocked     RowNum
-------------------------------------------
2015-02-09 07:00:00.000 0           1
2015-02-09 07:15:00.000 0           2
2015-02-09 07:30:00.000 0           3
2015-02-09 07:45:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 08:00:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 08:15:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 08:30:00.000 0           1
2015-02-09 08:45:00.000 0           2
2015-02-09 09:00:00.000 0           3
2015-02-09 09:15:00.000 0           4
2015-02-09 09:30:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 09:45:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 10:00:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 10:15:00.000 1           0
2015-02-09 10:30:00.000 0           1
2015-02-09 10:45:00.000 0           2
2015-02-09 11:00:00.000 0           3
2015-02-09 11:15:00.000 0           4
2015-02-09 11:30:00.000 0           5
2015-02-09 11:45:00.000 0           6
2015-02-09 12:00:00.000 0           7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just proceed with the case condition like this CASE WHEN Blocked= 0 then  ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY Blocked ORDER BY Blocked ) ELSE 0 END

Comment: Perhaps i didn't clarify enough - after finding 1 in "blocked" column, the counter have to restart as in the expected result example. Perhaps my terribad english is the issue.

Comment: will there ever be gaps in the data ?

Comment: i just gave you insight on how to proceed with the given blocked column

Comment: @t-clausen.dk The range of data will span over a week, between 7am and 7pm - so the gap will be between 7pm of one day and 7am of next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 you can solve it like this

```
SELECT Slot
      ,Blocked
      ,CASE WHEN Blocked = 0
                 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                 (PARTITION BY rt.RunningTotal ORDER BY Slot)
            ELSE 0 END RowNum
FROM Table1 t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Blocked), 0) RunningTotal
             FROM Table1
             WHERE Slot < t.Slot
            ) rt
ORDER BY Slot
```

(Replace Table1 with your table name)

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/659a0/28

Comment: seems your rownumber is failing on the first 3 rows. Same in your fiddle

Comment: As my edit suggestion was rejected (???) I write it as comment: You have to use `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Blocked), 0) RunningTotal` to avoid a own Partition for the first line caused by the lack of preceeding rows and thefore the RunningTotal being `null`.

Comment: @flo, it seems someone else rejected the edit suggestion you made. I have now made the edit, this solves the problem.

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl Sorry, I have not been clear about the reject. Of course it was not you but several moderators.

Comment: Accepted this solution because it was the easiest to implement for me - not sure which is best performance wise since it's not important at the moment. In two weeks our SQL guy comes back from the weekend :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using sqlserver 2008, you need to use row_number() over.
The calculation is a bit complex, but this script will work from sqlserver 2005.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SLOT, row_number() over (order by SLOT)-
row_number() over (partition by blocked order by SLOT) x, blocked
 FROM 
-- replace these lines with your real table
--start test tabel
(values 
(cast( '2015-02-09 07:00:00.000' as datetime), 0)
,('2015-02-09 07:15:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 07:30:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 07:45:00.000', 1),('2015-02-09 08:00:00.000', 1)
,('2015-02-09 08:15:00.000', 1),('2015-02-09 08:30:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 08:45:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 09:00:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 09:15:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 09:30:00.000', 1)
,('2015-02-09 09:45:00.000', 1),('2015-02-09 10:00:00.000', 1)
,('2015-02-09 10:15:00.000', 1),('2015-02-09 10:30:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 10:45:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 11:00:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 11:15:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 11:30:00.000', 0)
,('2015-02-09 11:45:00.000', 0),('2015-02-09 12:00:00.000', 0)) x(SLOT,Blocked )
-- end test tabel
)
SELECT 
  SLOT, 
  BLOCKED, 
  CASE WHEN blocked = 0 
    THEN
      row_number() over (partition by x, blocked order by slot) 
    ELSE 0 end ROWNUMBER
FROM cte
ORDER BY slot
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question..!!

I was able to achieve this using below code:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TestTable(SLOT DATETIME,BLOCKED INT);

    INSERT #TestTable(SLOT,BLOCKED)
    VALUES
    ('2015-02-09 07:00:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 07:15:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 07:30:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 07:45:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 08:00:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 08:15:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 08:30:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 08:45:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 09:00:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 09:15:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 09:30:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 09:45:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 10:00:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 10:15:00.000' ,1),
    ('2015-02-09 10:30:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 10:45:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 11:00:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 11:15:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 11:30:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 11:45:00.000' ,0),
    ('2015-02-09 12:00:00.000' ,0)


    SELECT *
    FROM #TestTable
    ORDER BY SLOT


    ;WITH TestTableVw AS
    (SELECT SLOT,BLOCKED,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  SLOT) RNum
     FROM #TestTable
    )
    SELECT T.SLOT,T.BLOCKED,CASE WHEN T.BLOCKED=0 THEN V1.RNum-ISNULL((SELECT MAX(V2.RNum) FROM TestTableVw V2 WHERE V2.RNum<V1.RNum AND V2.BLOCKED=1),0) ELSE 0 END
    FROM #TestTable T
    JOIN TestTableVw V1 ON T.SLOT=V1.SLOT

    DROP TABLE #TestTable;
```

I hope this will help..!!

Thanks,

Swapnil

Comment: @TotallyNewb: Check if the code which I provided works for you. i have tested this using the sample data that you provided. The code generates  expected output as given in the question..